# Solving an equation involving averages: $f(y)=(y-N\langle f(y)\rangle)^{-1}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have the following equation to solve for $f(y)$:
\begin{equation}
f(y)=(y-N\langle f(y)\rangle)^{-1}
\end{equation}
Where $N$ is a fixed integer, and $y$ is a random variable. $\langle \cdot\rangle$ denotes an average over the distribution of $y$.

If $y$ is deterministic then  $\langle f(y)\rangle=f(y)$ and the equation simply becomes:
\begin{equation}
f(y)=(y-N f(y))^{-1}\implies -Nf(y)^2+f(y)y-1=0
\end{equation}

However when $y$ actually follows a random distribution, it spices things up.
In the most simple case, when $y$ can only take two values $a$ or $b$ how can I solve the equation? i.e

when $P(Y=y)=p\delta(a-y)+(1-p)\delta(b-y)$ with $p\leq 1$

how can we solve :
\begin{equation}
f(y)=(y-N\langle f(y)\rangle)^{-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: You should write $x=f(y)$ to denote the dependence on $y$ because if someone misses that the brackets denote “an average over the distribution of $y$” it is easy to misinterpret what you wrote as $X=(Y-n\mathbb{E}(X))^{-1}$ which makes no sense.

Comment: @Nap D. Lover I'd have tought the opposite : I thought the OP means "find all $f$'s such that $X=f(Y)$ satisfies $X=\frac{1}{Y-n{\mathbb{E}}(X)}$ a.e. What else could the OP mean ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy now it is edited, clear and unambiguous, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it for a $y$ that takes a finite number of values,
say $y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_r$. Put $p_k=P(Y=y_k)$ and let $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$. Let $X$ be the random variable defined by $X=\frac{1}{Y-N\lambda}$.

We will have a solution to our problem iff ${\mathbb{E}}(X)=\lambda$, or in other words,

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac{p_k}{y_k-N\lambda} = \lambda \tag{1}
$$

Assuming the denominator is nonzero, this is equivalent to

$$
y_r = N\lambda +\frac{p_r}{\lambda - \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} \frac{p_k}{y_k-N\lambda} }
\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Very clear, thank you. I can also extend it for $y$ having a continuous random distribution, and simply having an integral in equation $(1)$? Or is it a bit more complicated?

Comment: @Matt It will depend on the distribution of $y$, of course. The simpler the distribution, the simpler the solution.